# Swift, Observer pattern with closures

Tags: swift, design-patterns, observer-pattern

I'm trying to implement the Observer pattern in swift using only functions:

```
var closures: [() -> Void] = []

class A: NSObject
{
    static var c = 0
    var i = 0

    override init()
    {
        super.init()
        self.i = A.c
        A.c += 1
    }

    func foo()
    {
        print("Hi: \(i)")
        print("\(A.c)")
    }
} // class

var aa:A? = A()

closures.append(aa!.foo)

for item in closures
{
    item()
}

aa = A()

for item in closures
{
    item()
}
```

this prints:

```
Hi: 0
1
Hi: 0
2
```

First question, it looks like the instance variable `i`  is never modified, do you know why?

Second question, will it leak memory? Since I have an array of functions, will `aa`ever be released without emptying the array?

Third question, any better idea for an Observe pattern using just functions? (I don't want to use protocols)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution using better keyword on google.
I needed to implement the observer pattern using closures, to avoid protocolos and thus decoupling of the observer to the observables.
The observer is an object with an array of closures like this one:
`var array:[() -> ()] = []`

Each observable add it's function to this array, when it's needed the observer will call each or any function of this array.
The functions are made as shown below.

`lazy var someClosure: () -> String = {
    [unowned self, ] in
    // closure body goes here
}`

To avoid retain cycles the `self` must be captured as `unowed` or `weak`.

Here is the article that exaplain with more details this solution: https://medium.cobeisfresh.com/why-you-shouldn-t-use-delegates-in-swift-7ef808a7f16b#.dmijmxbc4

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood the retain/release cycle. Let's walk through your code line by line:

```
var aa:A? = A()
```

Initialize a new instance of `A`. This memory has a retain count of 1.

```
closures.append(aa!.foo)
```

Append that instance of `A` to the `closures` array. The retain count is 2.

```
for item in closures
{
    item()
}
```

Call `foo` on the first instance of `A`.

```
aa = A()
```

Create another instance of `A`. The first instance continues to be retained by the array and the retain count drops to 1. But `A.c` is incremented because you coded it in the `init` method.

```
for item in closures
{
    item()
}
```

You are still calling the method on the first object. `A.c` is shared with the second object but `i` is not. The second object is never in the `closures` array.

Before I get to your other questions: why are you trying to do?

Comment: I guess the 'why' is a 'what'. I'm trying to implement an Observer pattern without using types. I'd have a class with an array of functions, objects like class A would add their functions to the array. When needed each of the functions of the array would be called. I could do the same using a Protocol, but I wanted to try something different.